# How do I change the scale of a graph made with Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I've drawn a LineChart using openpyxl and used the default style. I would like more granular control and change the scale of the graph. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

So, you can change the scale of the graph and add your maximum and minimum value between which the scale is limited.

Use the scaling.min/max present within the axes to change the scales. I've given the example code from [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/limits_and_scaling.html) which illustrates this.

```
# Sets the x axis between 0->11
chart2.x_axis.scaling.min = 0
chart2.x_axis.scaling.max = 11

# Sets the y axis between 0->1.5
chart2.y_axis.scaling.min = 0
chart2.y_axis.scaling.max = 1.5
```